# Why does python list resize overallocation differ from other languages?

Tags: python, arrays, memory-management, cpython

I've been reading a bit of python source code and found a [peculiar comment about the resize overallocation strategy](https://hg.python.org/releasing/3.4.2/file/10298f4f42dc/Objects/listobject.c#l25) -

```
/* This over-allocates proportional to the list size, making room
 * for additional growth.  The over-allocation is mild, but is
 * enough to give linear-time amortized behavior over a long
 * sequence of appends() in the presence of a poorly-performing
 * system realloc().
 * The growth pattern is:  0, 4, 8, 16, 25, 35, 46, 58, 72, 88, ...
 */
+
−new_allocated = (newsize >> 3) + (newsize < 9 ? 3 : 6);
```

I remembered the usual strategy is to double the capacity when the limit is reached.

I checked with a few other languages source code and found that indeed it is as I though, in [go](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/49342fe6f2ca6cedd5219d835a0a810e6f03cdd7/deps/v8/src/objects/js-objects.h#L542), [rust](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/0ca7f74dbd23a3e8ec491cd3438f490a3ac22741/src/liballoc/raw_vec.rs#L397) and [c#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.ensurecapacity?view=net-7.0)

Also I found out they [changed it a bit](https://bugs.python.org/issue38373) in the next python prerelease version, but for unrelated reasons - keeping the same concept of the strategy.

So why does python have such a unique method of resizing, and what are the implications on performance?

Comment: Short of getting an answer from the author of the code, that comment is probably as close as you're going to come to a "why" answer. A key phrase in that comment is "the over-allocation is mild". There is something extravagant in doubling the size of a list. Python's approach is to increase the size more slowly. It seems like a strategy that focuses on the use-case of smallish lists, while still giving amortized O(1) behavior for larger lists.

Comment: I believe the answer is in the comment right above the snippet you quoted.  There is no reason to prefer 2x over the roughly 1.125x used in Python. It really depends on what you think the usage is going to be.

Comment: @JohnColeman it is even weirder since the python dict implementation does [double the size](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8c2615decd2e/Objects/dictobject.c#l1256) on resize.